# First brew - What is a good SG for end of first fermentation?

Tags: fermentation, primary-fermentation

After my primary fermentation, ready to rack to carboi (about a week) my SG is about 1.015... is that anywhere near being good? Seems like that's what it started at. [image: this is a picture of said measurement]

It's a red ale from an extract kit. My first brew. The fermentation seemed a bit sketchy to begin with. Bubbled for a while then stopped after about 1/2 day. I tried to restart the yeast but figured meh... maybe it just had to big an air space and it didn't build up enough pressure to bubble.

I tasted the brew - tasted fine - like a flat bass ale. And it frothed up a bit when poured into the measurer. Ok that probably meant jack shit but still ... Any advice is well appreciated, including "dump it! run screaming!"

Comment: What was your initial gravity reading and what is it now? Did the recipe mention gravity values?

Comment: I looked at the recipe but I didn't see any comments on what the gravity should be for post-fermentation. It only stated what it should be when you throw the yeast into the wort, which was about the same. Sorry - I'm pretty new to this stuff so if my terms are off.... is it supposed to change over time?

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding comments. Comments are used to ask for clarification or to leave remarks that don't warrant an answer. If there are a lot of comments, some of them will not be shown initially, making it hard to puzzle all the extra information together. Make it easy for people to help you buy editing your question and merging new information in where it fits best.

Comment: Do you have a link to the kit and/or its recipe?  That would help us predict what your Original and Final Gravities should be.  Also, 1.015 would be extremely low for an Original Gravity and was probably measurement error.  You might want to have a look at the answers to http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/445/why-is-our-original-gravity-low .

Answer (score 3):

Being a red ale extract kit, it will have a reasonable amount of unfermentables in it.  Given that, I'd say you're in god shape.

Comment: I wish I were in god shape...(haha) ... I tend not to worry and as far as what I have read you shouldn't worry too much other than keeping things clean... which I am pretty certain we did. Well, thanks for the encouragement. I just really hope when we condition it in the bottle it gets bubbly....